# how to use setOnClickListerner correctly?

Tags: java, android

how to use setOnClickListerner correctly? I fixed the problem like error: incompatible type:  could not be converted to OnLongClickListener and it could not

```
        listViewDosen.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,View view, int i, long l){

            Data data = dosenList.get(i);
            showUpdateDialog(data.getId(),data.getNama());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ClickListener` then use `setOnItemClickListener` like the following.

```
listViewDosen.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       Data data = dosenList.get(position);
       showUpdateDialog(data.getId(),data.getNama());
   } 
});
```

If you want to use `LongClickListener` then use `setOnItemLongClickListener` insted of `setOnLongClickListener` like below.

```
listViewDosen.setOnItemLongClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Data data = dosenList.get(position);
     showUpdateDialog(data.getId(),data.getNama());
     return false;
  }
});
```